# Can you keep source formatting when reading Excel with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl, xlrd

Can Python read an Excel file while retaining the source format? The table below illustrates the source format; it is possible through Excel to CSV conversion; however, this method *will not* be the solution for the program.

| Currency | Percent | Date Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $345.0 | 50% | Mar-22 |

**CSV method that extracts source format:**

```
rows = []
with open('filename.csv') as file:
    csvreader = csv.reader(file)
    header = next(csvreader)
    for row in csvreader:
        rows.append(row)
print(header)
print(rows)
```

```
['Currency', 'Percent', 'Date Value']
[['$345.0', '50%', 'Mar-22']]
```

**Excel method that *DOES NOT* extract source format:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx', dtype=str)
print(df)
```

```
['Currency', 'Percent', 'Date Value']
[['345.0', '0.50', '2022-03-01 00:00:00']]
```

Comment: @NoobVB `dtype=str` was incorrectly reccomended on another post so I was hedging the potential of that solution being reccomended. @charlie-clark Openpyxl has the same issue where it automatically converts.

Answer (score 0):

You will likely need to create custom converter functions and pass them in as arguments to the `read_excel` function.

For Example:

```
def tocurrency(value):
    val = float(value)
    return f"${val:.2f}"

def topercent(value):
    val = float(value)
    return f"{val:.0%}"

def todate(value):
    return value.strftime("%b-%d")

df = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx', converters={"Currency":tocurrency, 
                                                "Percent": topercent, 
                                                "Date Value": todate})

print(df)
```

output:

```
  Currency Percent Date Value
0  $345.00     50%     Mar-22
```

Comment: Thank you for you comment; however, the source format will always be uncertain. For example, the column 'Currency' may be labeled 'State' with a completely different data type. Do you know if this is solvable?

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the dtype=str and instead provide a dictionary of datatypes that you wish to assign to those columns

For ex.

```
dtype = { "Currency" : int, "Percent" : float, "Date Value" : np.datetime64 }
```

Comment: Thank you for answering; however, per the above, I do not want the values to be converted from the source format. If you make currency an int, it will pass through as an int of 345 instead of the desired $345.